# Which "travel vaccinations" are available for free with the NHS in the UK?

Tags: uk, health, planning

NHS GP surgeries and clinics provide vaccinations for travel for free, but for only certain kinds of diseases.

Is there a comprehensive list of which "travel vaccinations" will be covered by the NHS (regardless of which country is the destination)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a comprehensive list of what vaccinations are provided by the NHS.

[It can be found on the NHS choices website](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Travel-immunisation/Pages/Introduction.aspx), which says:

> ## Free travel vaccinations
>
> The following travel vaccinations are usually available free on the NHS
>
> - diphtheria, polio and tetanus (combined booster)
> - typhoid
> - hepatitis A – including when combined with typhoid or hepatitis B
> - cholera
>
> These vaccines are usually free because they protect against diseases thought to represent the greatest risk to public health if they were brought into the country.

Interestingly it says "usually" rather than making a blanket statement. I'm not sure if this is because the decision is made at an individual trust/surgery level, or if they are just covering themselves.

Further down the page it also notes that:

> People in certain risk groups may be offered extra vaccines

I personally found that when I attempted to get Typhoid/hep A from the NHS, my GP had a temporary staffing issue with regards to nurses, and as a result simply said "we're not doing travel appointments". Which was somewhat frustrating, although they did at least provide a list of private suppliers.

At the time this answer was placed, the webpage stated it was last reviewed on 16/11/2015

I have no idea if this applies at all to the Scottish NHS.